# Castle Windsor - Removing or changing a registered instance

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, ioc-container

I want to change the registered instance with another instance created at runtime.

This can be removing existing component and re-registering the new one, or just reassigning the newly created instance to the registered one.

```
Foo old = new Foo("asd");
IoC.Register(Component.For<IFoo>().Instance(old));

Foo new = new Foo("qwe");
IoC.Unregister(old); // RemoveComponent method is removed from IKernel after v3.0
IoC.Register(Component.For<IFoo>().Instance(new));
```

Is there a way to do that? Please do not suggest other ideas such as "re-intialize your IoC container" etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9253388/in-castle-windsor-3-override-an-existing-component-registration-in-a-unit-test

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have to do this more than once, you could consider registering `IFoo` with `UsingFactoryMethod` and `Lifestyle.Transient`, so each time you get an instance it uses the latest parameters:

```
Component.For<IFoo>().UsingFactoryMethod(GetLatestFoo).Lifestyle.Transient

...


private IFoo GetLatestFoo()
{
    return new Foo(...)
}
```

Comment: This one was useful, also added "managedExternally: true" parameter to UsingFactoryMethod() to return singleton object which I reinstantiate whenever I want. A bit dirty solution though :)

Answer (score 2):

See this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16832183/4593944

Register the new component with `IsDefault` and it becomes the preferred resolver.

If you already have a container with instances that you want to reset, usually singletons, just call Dispose on container.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an [IHandlerSelector](http://ialekseev.blogspot.it/2012/10/how-to-remove-component-in-castle.html).

Comment: This example talks about switching from one implementation to another. In my code, I am using the same implementation, Foo, but want it to be reinstantiated with different parameters.

Comment: Ok. Understood. You may consider also a TypedFactory w/ a custom  ITypedFactoryComponentSelector.http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Typed-Factory-Facility-interface-based-factories.ashx?HL=typedfactory